# Hibernate case insensitive joins for Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm looking for a way for the sql generated by hql to use upper or lower as comparisons on joins. For example if I have

```
from EntityA a join fetch a.b
```

Which generates

```
... join table b on a.fk = b.pk
```

I would instead like

```
... join table b on upper(a.fk) = upper(b.pk);
```

I tried making the postgres columns citext, which makes them case insensitive, but that was causing lazy fetching issues with hibernate that I cannot figure out.  Thus I want to try altering hibernates behavior.

Comment: what is foreign key type, is it String

Comment: Yes.  I'm only concerned about strings.

Comment: does [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/28389-hibernate-case-insensitive-joins) help you

Comment: can you change column type to citext?